# Using id inside do notation

Tags: haskell, monads

I am watching a Haskell online course, Reader monad chapter. The instructor gives the following example:
this function takes a list and returns Nothing if it's empty or (Just head) otherwise.

```hs
safeHead = do
  -- argument is implicit here
  b <- null
  if b then
    return Nothing
  else do
    h <- head
    return $ Just h

safeHead' = do
  e <- id -- the error
  if (null e)
    then Nothing
    else return $ Just (head e)
```

The second function takes the list explicitly, using `e <- id`. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. ghci gives an error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe [a]’
              with actual type ‘a0 -> a0’
 • Probable cause: ‘id’ is applied to too few arguments
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: e <- id
    In the expression:
      do e <- id
         if (null e) then Nothing else return $ Just (head e)
```

This example was probably tested by the authors 3 years ago, when the course was created 
(or maybe, it was wrong from the beginning).

I have a suspicion that `null` takes a wrapped value, while `id` doesn't:

```
Prelude> :t null
null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool
Prelude> :t id
id :: a -> a
```

What's wrong and how to fix?

Comment: For better error messages, always provide a type signature for top-level bindings. In this case, GHC found a type mismatch and wrongly blamed `id`, when the error is actually otherwise, in `Nothing`. This happened because GHC had not enough information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you just forgot a `return`.  The following works fine:

```
safeHead' = do
  e <- id
  if (null e)
    then return Nothing         -- need return here
    else return $ Just (head e)
```

or you can factor the `return` out:

```
safeHead' = do
  e <- id
  return $ if (null e)
    then Nothing
    else Just (head e)
```